# Flutter application restart instead of resuming after invoking method from native Android

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I currently doing payment integration in Flutter using native Android.
I manage to get the results from the payments side, I then proceed to return the result into my invoking flutter file.

Here is the passing of my code to my invoking flutter file.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackToMerchantActivity.class);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("resultTitle",resultPaymentMessage.getStrResultTitle());
                        returnIntent.putExtra("resultInfo",resultPaymentMessage.getStrResultInfo());
                        returnIntent.putExtra("resultExtra",resultPaymentMessage.getStrResultExtra());

                        startActivity(returnIntent);
                        finish();
```

Here is my invoking methods

```
class BackToMerchantActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  private val CHANNEL = "my.com.ipay88.ipay88payment/backToMarchant"
  private lateinit var _result: MethodChannel.Result

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    print("Enter Back To Merchant \n");

    val resultTitle: String = intent.getStringExtra("resultTitle")  ?: ""
    val resultInfo: String = intent.getStringExtra("resultInfo")    ?: ""
    val resultExtra: String = intent.getStringExtra("resultExtra")  ?: ""

    print("Result title : " + resultTitle +" \n");
    print("Result Info  : " + resultInfo +" \n");
    print("Result Extra : " + resultExtra +" \n");

    MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).invokeMethod("my.com.ipay88.ipay88payment/backToMarchant", mapOf("resultTitle" to resultTitle, "resultInfo" to resultInfo, "resultExtra" to resultExtra));
  }
  
}
```

The results is able to into invoking files as I am able to print it out. However the invoking flutter application from native Android will restart the whole Flutter application instead of resuming the application. Please help as I been stuck here for a week. Any tips would be really appreciated

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm opening a wallet external app from native code. When I  return from it, Flutter app showing restarted UI

Comment: @FaslurRajah Hi, the solution i found is by using Flutter android_intent package to invoke wallet external app.